# Jquery load doesn't work when page is not opened through localhost/ (xampp server)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Anyone could help me explain why when I open the same file (one I place it in desktop and another I place it in the htdocs folder inside xampp) exactly the same file. When I open the file in the desktop, the jquery load() doesn't work, but when I open the file in the xampp folder, the jquery load() works fine.

I understand in the case of php file, the page need to be inside xampp folder to works, but these are only html file, does jquery load need to uses server-side scripting ?? Please help me explain this.

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src='./js/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div").load("test.txt");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class='div'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.txt :

```
test
```

my folder structure :

```
test
  >> js
     >> jquery.js
  >> test.html
  >> test.txt
```

Comment: `.load()` is an ajax method ... and you need a web server for ajax to work in most browsers.

Comment: when you move the file to desktop how do you write the path to the file? `.load("path/to/the/file/test.txt")` how does it looks like?

Comment: no, I don't write the path, I just wrote .load('test.txt') cause they are in the same folder right, but yeah my best guess is that it needs a server to works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are including JQuery relative to the document you are loading:

```
<script src='./js/jquery.js'></script>
```

If you change that to:

```
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>
```

It should work from anywhere as you are loading jQuery from a remote CDN instead of locally.

Comment: better would be `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` since we don't know if he is using SSL or not.

Comment: well I am hosting my own jquery script which I put in a folder called js inside the same folder with the same test.html and test.txt, I ll put my directory structure on top

Comment: When you then put your file on the desktop you also have to put your jQuery there.

Comment: yes I do, directory structure on top, and I tried using the same exact folder, one in desktop, and one in xampp folder, exactly the same in every thing, but the one in xampp folder jquery load works fine, the one with the desktop doesn't